# Use UISearchBar with Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, uisearchbar

I am trying to use `UISearchBar` with Firebase but I get an error when I try to type any right word

- My Code is

  ```
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
  var isSearching: Bool = false
  //list to store all the artist
  var hotelList = [hotelsModel]()
  var filterHotels = [hotelsModel]()
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  if isSearching{
      return filterHotels.count
  } else {
  return hotelList.count
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  //creating a cell using the custom class
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! hotelsTableViewCell

  //the artist object
  let hotel: hotelsModel
  //getting the artist of selected position
  hotel = hotelList[indexPath.row]

  //adding values to labels
  cell.lblName.text = hotel.name
  cell.lblLocation.text = hotel.location
  cell.appSuggest.text = hotel.appSuggest
  cell.price.text = hotel.price
  cell.canceletion.text = hotel.cancelation
  cell.paymentNeeded.text = hotel.paymentNeeded
  if isSearching{
      cell.lblName?.text = filterHotels[indexPath.row].name
  }

  return cell
  }
  func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

  if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
      isSearching = false
      view.endEditing(true)
      tableView.reloadData()
  } else {
      isSearching = true
      filterHotels = hotelList.filter({$0.name == searchBar.text})
      tableView.reloadData()
  }
  }
  ```
- in this line

  ```
  if isSearching{

      cell.lblName?.text = filterHotels[indexPath.row].name
  }
  ```

  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSsP4.png]
- this's my code files 
  if someone can check it

  https://github.com/HaMaDaRaOuF/UISearchBar-Firabse

**thank you**

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: okay but i already upload my code in link but i'll edit my qution with my code also

Comment: What's the error? Nobody's going to download, build, and run unfamiliar code just to see the error that you could have copied & pasted here.

Comment: already added my code and image by error

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to change the filter process (smth like this):

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String) {

    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
    filteredHotels = hotelList?.filtered(using: pred) as? [hotelsModel]

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and change the isSearching variable to this:

```
var isSearching: Bool {
    return searchBar.text != ""
}
```

Use the debugger to see the indexPath.row value on the line that is causing your crash.

Comment: Thank You gays my problim it's was in the Number Of Rows In Section Function it's havn't return for filterHotels i edit my qution if someone need the code also i'll edit it in github `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      
        if isSearching{
            return filterHotels.count
        } else {
        return hotelList.count
        }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Thank You guys my problem it's was in the Number Of Rows In Section Function it's haven't return for `filterHotels` I edit my question if someone need the code also i'll edit it in github

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->  Int { if isSearching{ return filterHotels.count } else { return hotelList.count } }
```

- Github Link
  https://github.com/HaMaDaRaOuF/UISearchBar-Firabse